# Override TalkBack text for a LinearLayout containing an icon and a TextView

Tags: android, accessibility

I basically have this:

```
<MyCustomLinearLayout>
  <ImageView>
  <TextView>
</MyCustomLinearLayout>
```

I want to override the accessibility text of the entire layout substructure; when the LinearLayout or either of its children are tuoched, I'd like to completely control what TalkBack says (so I can make it say "3 comments" instead of "Comment Icon 3").

I've tried various combinations of overriding `sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked`, `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent`, `requestSendAccessibilityEvent`, etc. to no avail, and I can't find an example of this fairly simple setup anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use [View.setContentDescription()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on your layout to dynamically set the text and prevent TalkBack from reading the contents of child views.

```
myText.setText(text);
. . .
myLayout.setContentDescription(imageDescription + " " + text);
```

Since you're setting the description dynamically, you can set the image's content description to @null in your layout XML to avoid Lint errors.

```
<ImageView
    . . .
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

Also consider watching the recent Android Developer Office Hours video on [Making Android Apps Accessible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPKKHNuVmeA), which covers these topics and many more.